# How can I enforce that unit tests are run on Gradle Android build?

Tags: android, unit-testing, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Hello fine android devs!

(I understand that this is a very basic question. I'm still wrapping my head around Gradle and Android, and my Googling on this particular one turns up nothing.)

I have my first unit test written, and it runs fine using

```
./gradlew test
```

I'm not exactly sure what is making it run since the test directory (src/test/java/tld/mycompany/myapp/MyTest.java) is not in build.gradle or app/build.gradle, but I'm assuming that it is performed by magic in the Android Gradle plugin. Either way, when I choose "Rebuild Project", the tests are not included in the build - if I intentionally break on of the tests, the build still succeeds.

How do I make the build run the tests and fail if the tests fail?

Answer (score 0):

"Rebuild Project" just downloads the depenencies and compiles the code. If you want to build the project properly, use

```
./gradlew build
```

The reason the tests are run even if you don't declare them anywhere is, as you said, part of the android gradle plugin. The tests in /test/ and /androidTest/ are both executed because of predefined build types.
With ./gradlew build, ALL present build types will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

If you look [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html), you'll see the relationship between the gradle tasks for java (which is what it's using in Android).

As tknell has said, both test and androidTest are executed because they're 'marked' as test directories in the imported android plugin.

What the 'rebuild project' task does is look at the build.gradle file and see which dependencies and such are declared. Based on that, it builds its project for Android Studio. This (as far as I know) doesn't run any real gradle tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You can not "Rebuild Project" with running your unit test. But you can create your custom run for checking unit tests. By `Run > Edit Configuration`.
You can see more here. http://rexstjohn.com/unit-testing-with-android-studio/